# Python: Move a directory based on name

Tags: python, directory

In a directory "A" i have several directories names "abc_123","abc_124" and so on. also in directory "A" i have directories named "anc_123","anc_124" and so on. and also several other directories in it.

My question is how would i move only directories starting with "abc_***" to a different location. I'm new to python and don't know how to proceed on this one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In bash: `mv abc_* new_location/`

Comment: I'm trying to write a python program, does the above answer apply as well

Comment: The simplest solution would be to avoid Python and use command-line tools which are designed for moving files. If you insist on doing this in Python, you will need to use the functions in the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module, likely at least `listdir` and `rename`.

Comment: If you'd like to use the shell route, python is good at executing shell commands; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/1275942 for a number of ways to do it. That said, it's fine to do it within python as well--python's support for file operations is about as good, if you're used to it. That also has the benefit of being more portable--if you're running your code on windows, bash might be iffy, but python's libraries hopefully still work.

Answer (score 0):

[shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)'s `move(src, dst) method` will move a directory.

[os.listdir(dir)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) can list all files and directories within a directory. You could then simply do a string comparison to test if the directories start with `abc`.

However, [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) might be the best choice. `glob.glob("directory/abc_*")` will return a list of all files/directories of `directory` starting with `abc`.

You'll also want to check if the files are files or directories, for which `os.path.isdir` is useful.

```
import glob
import os
import os.path
import shutil

files = glob.glob("abc_*") # will return a list, like ["abc_123", "abc_345"]
for file in files:
    if os.path.isdir(file):
        shutil.move(file, "dest/")
```

Comment: when I try the above code its giving me empty list in files=glob.glob("abc.*") step

Comment: @apilat I'm trying to implement this functionality in python program

Comment: `_`, not `.`, assuming your file is `abc_123`. Read the examples on the glob docs page for more information on how to customize the glob

Comment: https://pymotw.com/2/glob/ looks like it also has examples

Comment: that was a typo, but when I'm trying it and print(files) i get empty list

Comment: This is probably a issue with working directories. `os.getcwd()` will give you the directory that python is executing in. You need to provide a relative path from that directory to the directory where the `abc` folders are. You can also provide an absolute path